# How to get new pandas dataframe with max value of k consecutive rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
ts = pd.Series([2372, 4356, 3034, 1502, 676, 4187, 2634, 1002])
```

What I would like to get is a dataframe which exists of the max value of four consecutive rows of the column and keeps index of row 0, 4, 8 etc.

In this case, this means a new dataframe should look like this one:

```
0 4356 

4 4187
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [899]: df = ts.groupby(np.arange(len(ts))//4).agg(['idxmax','max'])

In [900]: df
Out[900]: 
   idxmax   max
0       1  4356
1       5  4187
```

Comment: `ts.groupby(np.arange(len(ts))//4).agg(['idxmax','max'])` saves you one groupby :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! @MayankPorwal and Quang Hoang

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ts.groupby((np.arange(len(ts))//4)*4).max()
```

Output:

```
0    4356
4    4187
dtype: int64
```